# Artisan unable to access environment variables from $_ENV

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Any artisan command I enter into the command line throws this error:

```
$ php artisan
<?
return array(
    'DB_HOSTNAME'   => 'localhost',
    'DB_USERNAME'   => 'root',
    'DB_NAME'       => 'pc_booking',
    'DB_PASSWORD'   => 'secret',
);
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/martin/code/www/pc_backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/EnvironmentVariables.php on line 35
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined index: DB_HOSTNAME","file":"\/home\/martin\/code\/www\/pc_backend\/app\/config\/database.php","line":57}}
```

**This is only on my local development system, where I recently installed apache and php. On my production system on a shared host artisan commands work just fine.** The prod system has it's own .env.php, but other than that the code should be identical.

Relevant files:

*.env.local.php*

```
<?
return array(
    'DB_HOSTNAME'   => 'localhost',
    'DB_USERNAME'   => 'root',
    'DB_NAME'       => 'pc_booking',
    'DB_PASSWORD'   => 'secret',
);
```

*app/config/database.php*

```
<?php

return array(

'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

'default' => 'mysql',

'connections' => array(

    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => $_ENV['DB_HOSTNAME'],
        'database'  => $_ENV['DB_NAME'],
        'username'  => $_ENV['DB_USERNAME'],
        'password'  => $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'],
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
),

'migrations' => 'migrations',

),

);
```

The $_ENV array is populated as expected on the website - the problem appears to be with artisan only.

Comment: Looks like Laravel doesn't know you want the ``local`` environment and defaults to ``production`` instead. Try running ``php artisan –env-=local``, if that works you'll have confirmed that it's the issue. you can run ``hostname`` to find your local hostname out, then edit ``bootstrap/start.php`` to automatically map your local development system to the ``local`` environment.

Comment: Does not work. Laravel does recognize the environment and populate the $_ENV array on the server. There's only a problem when using Artisan.

Comment: Well, if Laravel recognises the environment on your local machine and still doesn't load the .env.local.php file, then I'm clueless too.

Comment: In case I was unclear. When I said that it recognizes it on the server I meant on the website, in the browser. As opposed to the command-line with artisan.

Comment: Your question says "On my production system on a shared host artisan commands work just fine", though. I thought it worked on the server - website and command-line both - but not locally on the command-line.

Comment: That's correct. It works everywhere except the command-line on my development system.

Comment: What happens if you change your ``bootstrap/start.php`` to ``$env = 'local';``, just for testing, do you get the same error? I'm sorry if it seems like I'm going in circles, but it's working fine for me.

Comment: That results in another error 'Class env does not exist'. Hey no problem thank you for trying to help! I wish we could move this discussion to chat though.

Comment: Yeah, that would have been nice. Next step: change it to this and see what happens. ``$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function() { return 'local'; });`` (linebreaks screwed by formatting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally figured out how to fix it.
It turns out that the file was not processed as a php file because I was using a short opening tag in the .env.local.php file. Using a normal opening tag solved it. I don't know why though, as short tags work fine elsewhere.

Comment: Ah, I'd have never caught that. Glad you managed to solve it. :)